# Raw sql where value is array. Ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to do the following

```
ElectricityProfile.find_by_sql ["select * from electricity_profiles where owner_id IN ?", array]
```

However seems that sql doesn't accept arrays.

Is there any other way to check column against array?

Using:
Rails 3.2.x
Ruby 193
MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need braces around the `?`.

```
ElectricityProfile.find_by_sql ["select * from electricity_profiles where owner_id IN (?)", array]
```

or

```
ElectricityProfile.where("owner_id IN (?)", array)
```

Comment: Sweet! The first one works, I don't want to use ActiveRecord for this purpose

Comment: You know that `find_By_sql` is also part of `ActiveRecord` right? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class

Comment: @DanMyasnikov by the way, the less you accept answer, the less you will have people answering your questions.

Comment: sorry mate, to much of rush

Answer (score -2):

Use the below.

```
           ElectricityProfile.find_by_sql("select * from electricity_profiles where owner_id in (?)", array])
```

Comment: Please update your answer as you don't use raw sql. It is ActiveRecord method

Comment: it's better to use ActiveRecord. Because it's more efficient.

Comment: You are wrong, ActiveRecord is nicer to use, however raw sql has better performance over the large chunk of data.